# Group lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple datasets that I have collected and I would like to visualize on the same graph.  Each set is composed of multiple lines that I would like to display as the same color.

Questions:

- How do I get the legend to only display one entry per color?
- Can I show/hide one group at a time?
- Additionally, I want to be able to show/hide individual curves
- Am I going about this correctly, or should I be using a different technique? Perhaps overlayed subplots?

Relevant Posts:

- [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978254/customizing-legend-in-matplotlib) has a similar end goal to what I am trying to do, but was never answered.
- [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978254/customizing-legend-in-matplotlib) talks about answering the legend question using handles, but I do not think is applicable to handling an arbitrary number of datasets and then handles would not work for showing/hiding as they only access the last element put in

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

  labels=['set a','set b','set c']
  V=np.arange(.1,10,.1)
  datasets=[]
  for i in range(3):
      set=[]
      for j in range(10):
          sweep=np.exp(i*V)+np.random.rand()
          set.append(sweep)
      datasets.append(set)



  colors=iter(plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(datasets))))
  for i,set in enumerate(datasets):
      c=next(colors)
      for j,sweep in enumerate(set):
          plt.plot(V,sweep,c=c,label=labels[i]+str(j))

  plt.xscale('log')
  plt.yscale('log')
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
  ```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd use Ipython widgets to select datasets. Could you give an executable example with some random data?

Comment: I added an executable example.  The details about any of this can be changed.  I'd prefer to be handling the problem the most flexible way as will end up doing this a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the show and hide full groups at a time, but I have answered all of the other questions by using two legends.  You can create an [interactive legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410043/hiding-lines-after-showing-a-pyplot-figure) with all of the entries in it, then create a [second legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph) with only the entries you want.  I then make everything I want and drag the interactive legend out of the plot area and will crop it.